# Npm Archiver to replace a file in zipped folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-archiver

Here is my api below.

```js
app.post('/downloadproject', function(req, res) {

    var projectName = 'web';
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
    res.set('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${projectName}.zip`);

    var zip = Archiver('zip');
    var adminZip=require('adm-zip');
    var zipper = new adminZip();
            // Send the file to the page output.
    zip.pipe(res);
    zip.directory(`projects/${projectName}/`, projectName);

    editPom(req.body,function(){
        // zipper.addLocalFile('temp/pom.xml','web/pom.xml');
        zip.file('temp/pom.xml',{name:"web/pom.xml"});
        zip.finalize().then(function(){
            console.log('Zip completed');
        });
    });
});
```

In the above api call I am zipping the project folder, (using *archiver* in npm), that I need to download in the browser when **downloadProject** is called.

In the below line I am trying to replace the `pom.xml` with my local `pom.xml` file while zipping.

```js
zip.file('temp/pom.xml',{name:"web/pom.xml"});
```

But I am unable to do this. This is duplicating the `pom.xml` file.

The original and copied one are both being left in the folder.

Can anyone please help. Thanks in advance.